# Link to an attachment

Tags: rally

I'm trying to figure out a way to pull up a link to an attachment that a user story may have but I havent been able to figure out how. As I have it, the only thing I get in that column is "[object Object]" when a user story has an attachment.

There doesnt appear to be much out there on grabbing attachments, if anyone can shed any light or point me in the right direction, I'd surely appreciate it!

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Table</title>
   <meta name="Name" content="App Example: Table" />
   <meta name="Version" content="2010.4" />
   <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.24/sdk.js?loginKey=bignumber"></script>  
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function tableExample() {
       var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('12345', '12345',       'True', 'True');
      function itemQuery() {
         var queryObject = {
           key: 'stories',
           type: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
           fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,ScheduleState,Description,Attachments',
           query: '(Name contains "release")'
         };
         rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
      }

      function populateTable(results) {
         var tableDiv = document.getElementById('aDiv');
         var config = { columns: 
             [{key: 'FormattedID', header: 'Formatted ID', width: 100}, 
             {key: 'Name', width: 400}, 
             {key: 'ScheduleState', header: 'Schedule State', width: 200},
             {key: 'Description', width: 800},
             {key: 'Attachments', header: 'Attachment Link', width: 200}]};
        var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);

     table.addRows(results.stories);
         table.display(tableDiv);

      };
      itemQuery();
     }

     rally.addOnLoad(tableExample);
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="aDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm including a slightly modified version of your App sample that does some post-processing to pull the Object ID of each attachment and drops it into some HTML links that are updated into the relevant table column.

```
        <html>
        <head>
           <title>Table</title>
           <meta name="Name" content="App Example: Stories with Attachments" />
           <meta name="Version" content="2010.4" />
           <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software" />
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.29/sdk.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">

             var table = null;

             function tableExample() {
               var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                                                                                    '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                                                                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                                                                                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
              function itemQuery() {
                 var queryObject = {
                   key: 'stories',
                   type: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
                   fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,ScheduleState,Description,Attachments,ObjectID'
                   // query: '(Name contains "release")'
                 };
                 rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
              }

              function populateTable(results) {

                  if (table) {
                      table.destroy();
                  }

                 var tableDiv = document.getElementById('aDiv');

                 var config = { 'columnKeys'    : ['FormattedID',  'Name', 'ScheduleState',   'Attachments'],
                                'columnHeaders' : ['FormattedID',  'Name', 'ScheduleState',   'Attachments'],
                                'columnWidths'  : ['100px',        '400px', '85px',           '300px']
                               };
                 table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);
                 table.addRows(results.stories);

                 for (i=0;i<results.stories.length;i++) {

                     myStory = results.stories[i];
                     myAttachments = results.stories[i].Attachments;

                     myAttachmentHTML = "";
                     for (j=0;j<myAttachments.length;j++) {
                         myAttachmentOID = myAttachments[j].ObjectID;
                         myAttachmentName = myAttachments[j].Name;
                         myAttachmentURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/attachment/"+
                                 myAttachmentOID + "/" + myAttachmentName;

                         myAttachmentHTML += "<div><a href='" + myAttachmentURL + "'>" +
                                 myAttachmentName + "</a></div>";

                     }
                     table.setCell(i, 3, myAttachmentHTML);
                 }
                 table.display(tableDiv);

              };
              itemQuery();
             }

             rally.addOnLoad(tableExample);
           </script>
        </head>
        <body>
           <div id="aDiv"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I should point out that this method:  rally.sdk.util.Context.getServerInfo().getSlmUrl() is a more elegant and supported way to grab the URL of the Rally server itself, as opposed to hard-coding as in the example I posted...